# Xamarin.Mobile Geolocator reporting 0 heading for android

Tags: android, xamarin, geolocation

I am trying to build an application that uses geolocation and the compass to indicate a direction.

I am using Xamarin.Forms with the Xamarin.Mobile component

> https://components.xamarin.com/view/xamarin.mobile

Here is the geolocation code:

```
private void UpdateHeading (object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    #if __ANDROID__
    var locator = new Geolocator (Forms.Context)
    #else
    var locator = new Geolocator ()
    #endif
    { DesiredAccuracy = 1 };

    locator.GetPositionAsync (timeout: 10000).ContinueWith (t => {
        var position = t.Result;

        // position.Heading == 0
    }, TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext());
}
```

On iOS, everything seems to work fine.
On Android it's a different story though: most of the time, `position.Heading` is set to `0`. However, `Latitude` and `Longitude` are correct.

I am new to Android development as well, so there may be something I'm missing here. Can I fix this / what's the best approach to have a reliable heading?

Comment: First, Your device support CompassHeading? You can check using Xamarin.Geolocation.Geolocator.SupportsHeading. Also are using the ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION permission ?

Comment: I do not believe that heading is supported on Android in the Xamarin.Mobile pack. See the code here: https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Mobile/blob/master/MonoDroid/Xamarin.Mobile/Geolocation/Geolocator.cs#L58 what you will see is that no where does heading get set and the supports heading is always false. However, you might want to look at the Device Mobile Plugin and it's compass functionality: https://github.com/rdelrosario/xamarin-plugins/tree/master/DeviceMotion

Comment: Also, you could try out my Geolocator plugin so you don't need to conditionally compile anything: https://github.com/jamesmontemagno/Xamarin.Plugins/tree/master/Geolocator  it is a nice cross platform wrapper around xamarin.mobile.

Comment: @GuilhermeTorresCastro Indeed, `Geolocator.SupportsHeading` is false :( Well spotted!

Comment: @JamesMontemagno, I'll have a look at your plugin. Thanks :) How stable do you think it is?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As pointed out by Guilherme, `Geolocator.SupportsHeading` is False for Android.